# Two bootable drives in one PC - which one boots?

Tags: boot, grub2, bios

As I build PCs out of parts scavenged from other PCs, I've encountered a situation new to me.

I have hard drives X and Y from 2 PCs.  Both were the "system disk" in their respective PCs, both have GRUB installed in their respective sda.  Both disks have partitions separate from the system partitions with data that I wish to keep.

I wish to install both drives in a PC.  I want the system to boot off drive X and ignore the fact that drive Y is bootable.

Is this done by setting boot order in the BIOS, or by manipulating something on the drives (unsetting the boot flag on Y's sda1 partition, for example)?

The "new" system is 64 bit but has a traditional BIOS, no UEFI.  The disks are MBR partitioned.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic since it has no direct relation to Ubuntu.

Comment: Makes sense.  But I didn't know that until I got the answer :)

Comment: My system has a traditional BIOS but both SATA and PATA.  It can boot whatever drive I choose.  However, that means that whatever drive I choose remains the default boot drive until I go back into BIOS to change it again.  It also doesn't care where the drive is on the cable.  As long as it can see the drive it can try to boot to the drive.   Mine's a MSI MS-7508 board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of PATA, the computer will boot from whichever drive is set as the master. The slave cannot be booted, at least in my experience. Most drives are on cable-select, which means their location on the PATA cable (end or middle) determines their role (master or slave, respectively). In this case, if you have it, the computer will ignore the drive set as slave, either from the cable or manual jumper selection and try to boot from the master.

SATA is a bit different. Every drive is a "master" and there are no slaves. However, there is still a priority. By default, the computer will try to boot into SATA 0 first. If it can't, it moves onto SATA 1, then onto SATA 2 and so on, until it runs out of drives. SATA has a nice feature that PATA doesn't have: you can always go into the BIOS boot menu and select which drive to boot from, as long as the BIOS can find a UEFI or Legacy bootable partition. You should also be able to manually edit the priority of the drives, so, if you want, SATA 2 will be booted from first, then SATA 0, then SATA 1.

So, if you have PATA, then you need to make sure that drive X is set as the master and Y is the slave. The first thing to try for that would be to put X on the end of the cable and Y in the middle. If that doesn't work, you'll have to play around with the jumpers on the drives. Both may be manually set to master, which will prevent boot.

If you have SATA, then you should be able to just set a priority in BIOS, but it would be better to put X in SATA 0 and Y in SATA 1, just so that you can be sure X will be tried first as a boot option.

Comment: Thanks, great info.  I should have mentioned that the system used SATA.  This must have been one of the last PCs before UEFI.  Which works for me.